# Not finding library activities declarations in the manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest, library-project

I have some project as a library named `LibProj`. It has a lot of activities that I want to use in `MainProj` project but I'm getting **Activity Not Found** error.

I have done these steps.

one of them is shown below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("packagename//ex-com.hello", 
                                     "classname//ex-com.hello.ExampleActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Second one is to add all activities' declarations in manifest of my `MainProj` project.

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.doocat.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity
                android:name=".activity.main.IntroActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name=".activity.main.LoginActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
```

etc...

Both of these ways not working. What I'm doing wrong or what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register Your Library Activity in MainProject manifest file..

I have given **action name** in **intent-filter**

**com.lib.Example** to identify which Activity need to call.

```
<activity
        android:name="YOUR_LIBRARY_ACTIVITY_PACKAGE. ExampleActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.lib.Example" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Now call this Activity from your MainProject

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.lib.Example");
try {
startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

}
```

Hope This help you.

Comment: Thanks, I have missed to add packages))